# DRF nested json unable get user detail

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework, and am building organization and user detail functionality. My models, serializer and model viewset details are like this.

```
class OrganizationLatest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    createdat = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedat = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'organization'
```

Serializer for Organization and User are as follows

```
class organizationLatestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=OrganizationLatest
        fields =('name','address','user')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk','username',)
        read_only_fields = ['id','username']

class OrganizationLatestVieset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = OrganizationLatest.objects.all()  # dummy objec
       serializer_class = organizationLatestSerializer
```

Rest api returns

```
[
    {
        "name": "Org1",
        "address": null,
        "user": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "Org2",
        "address": null,
        "user": 3
    },

]
```

But I want JSON in this format,

```
[
  {
    "name": "Org1",
    "address": "xxxxx",
    "user": [
      {
        "username": "jhon",
        "email": "a@g.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Org2",
    "address": "998,abc",
    "user": [
      {
        "username": "jhon",
        "email": "a@g.com"
      }
    ]
  }      
]
```

Please let me know how can I achieve expected json format.

Thank you all,

Comment: OrganizationLatest have a 1-M relationship with User, so instance of OrganizationLatest obviously will not have a list of users, only one user instance is attached to it, so your expected json already contains issue. `user` field value should be object in json response, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **OrganizationLatest** model as you defined in question, below code snippet will give your desired JSON, but `user` field will be an object or you can say user detail of linked user to `OrganizationLatest` instance.

```py
class OrganizationUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email',)
        read_only_fields = ['id','username']

class OrganizationLatestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = OrganizationUserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model=OrganizationLatest
        fields =('name','address','user')

class OrganizationLatestVieset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = OrganizationLatest.objects.all() 
       serializer_class = organizationLatestSerializer
```

Now, you will get output json on list endpoint like this :-

```
[
  {
    "name": "Org1",
    "address": "xxxxx",
    "user": {
      "username": "jhon",
      "email": "a@g.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Org2",
    "address": "998,abc",
    "user": {
      "username": "jhon",
      "email": "a@g.com"
    }
  }
]
```

> **Note** I am not recommeding you to change `UserSerializer` and use it instead of `OrganizationUserSerializer`, to show user in `OrganizationLatestSerializer`

Comment: what changes I have to make in model, serilizer and viewset to get design result?